# HTTP Callout with form-data not working

Tags: apex, integration, callout

I am making a callout to a payment gateway, and initially I tested the API using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) app.

[image]

And the response is given

[image]

Now, that I transform all that to Salesforce Apex, I am getting following error:

> RESPONSE:
>   {"method":"unknown","trace":"4001/10644/5bb4e0c6","error":{"message":"E01:Invalid
>   request","note":"Unknown method"}}

---

```
Http h = new Http(); 
String url = 'https://secure.telr.com/gateway/order.json';

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
System.debug('Complete URL: ' + url);
req.setEndpoint(url );
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
req.setMethod('POST');
  req.setBody('{"ivp_store":"21025","ivp_authkey":"<it\'s a secret to everyone>","ivp_currency":"AED","ivp_amount":"2","ivp_test":"1","ivp_cart":"ORD113","return_auth":"https://www.google.com","return_decl":"https://www.google.com","return_can":"https://www.google.com","ivp_desc":"TEST description","ivp_method":"create"}');
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

System.debug('RESPONSE: ' + res.getBody());
```

Comment: Your payment gateway appears to be expecting a `x-www-form-urlencoded` payload, not a JSON payload. Did you check to make sure `application/json` is supported?

Comment: As a heads-up, you posted your auth key in your code example. I've edited that out, but it would be a good idea to get that changed.

Comment: @sfdcfox yeah I am sure that is the issue, but the documentation on the payment gateway doesn't mention specifically. From the postman request, though, both the form data and url-encoded requests are working. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears your payment gateway wants a form post. You would need to change the following line:

```
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

And change your parameter building section as follows:

```
// Following URL can be anything; we only care about the query string
PageReference ref = new PageReference('https://contoso.com/');
// Populate parameters
Map<String, String> params = new Map<String, String>();
params.put('ivp_method','create');
params.put('ivp_desc','Test description - order');
// ... add remaining parameters here ...
ref.getParameters().putAll(params);
Url finalUrl = new Url(ref.getUrl());
// fully url-encoded query string - set the body of http request object
req.setBody(finalUrl.getQuery()));
```

This is the most literal translation of the Postman post in your screenshot.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. One question, could we not have appended all the parameters as query string to the API endpoint? (I will play around with that myself, but checking with the guru). :D

Comment: @Mahmood Sure, you *can*, but the benefit of doing it this way is automatic parameter escaping. So, rather than calling EncodingUril.urlEncode on a bunch of parameters, I let the PageReference class build my parameter list for me without worrying about escaping the parameters. This will be beneficial for you to make sure that nothing breaks when punctuation is used, etc. The general rule is "avoid building URLs/XML/JSON strings by hand"; it's far less likely to make a mistake if you use the tools provided to you.